# What is the difference between に and と with 間違われる?

Tags: grammar

> このうち、イギリスの新聞「デイリー・ミラー」は「マフィア**に間違われる**として、スター選手たちのタトゥーに警告」という見出しで伝えています。([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180925/k10011643191000.html?utm_int=news_contents_netnewsup_002))
>
> 彼は背が高いのでしばしば大人**と間違われる**([EJJE weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%E9%96%93%E9%81%95%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B))。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, both are acceptable.
Example:
僕は叔父に間違えられた
I was mistaken for my uncle.
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/間違う/#je-71688](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E9%96%93%E9%81%95%E3%81%86/#je-71688)

Although に is ambiguous.
マフィアに間違われる can be interpreted either as "to be mistaken as a mafia" or "to be mistaken by the mafia".

Comment: Exampleには「間違**え**られた」を使っているのですが、質問者は「間違**わ**れる」について聞いています。「間違われる」の場合の「に」と「と」の使い方についても触れてくれませんか。

Comment: どちらも同じです.......

Comment: @user4092 微妙な違いがあるようです。[参考](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/term/057.html)

Comment: 助詞の使い方については同じです